# How to create a 3 way emission gradient in blender 2.81?

Tags: materials, text-object, emission

I want to create a 3 way emission gradient that goes red-orange-red in blender 2.81 on text. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use an Object Texture Coordinate, connected to a ColorRamp that has your color arrangement (red-yellow-red), then connect that to an Emission Shader, and then connect that to the Material Output.

Comment: Please could you add a photo or something of what you want?